# Image out of circle

Tags: html, css

How to put placehold it image into circle with overflow: hidden;
Here is code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWaWYL. When I clicked on Image with lib transit image go up. But I need to see image into the circle

Html

```
 <body>
     <div id="del-countdown"> 
      <div id="screen"></div>
      <div id="clock"></div>

      <div id="units">
        <span>Hours</span>
        <span>Minutes</span>
        <span>Seconds</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box; }
body {
  background: #282e3a;
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 74px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#del-countdown {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;

  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

  /*background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3) ;*/

  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000ff;
  z-index: 0;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#clock,#units {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#screen{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1000%C3%97700&w=1000&h=700) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

#clock span {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 84px;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#clock span:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa5559;
}
#clock span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #26c2b9;
}
#clock span:nth-child(3) {
  background: #f6bc58;
}

#clock:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#units span {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.7);
}


span.turn {
  animation: turn 0.7s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

JS

```
"use strict";

function updateTimer(deadline) {
  var time = deadline - new Date();
  return {
    hours: Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24),
    minutes: Math.floor(time / 1000 / 60 % 60),
    seconds: Math.floor(time / 1000 % 60),
    total: time
  };
}

function animateClock(span) {
  span.className = "turn";
  setTimeout(function () {
    span.className = "";
  }, 700);
}

function startTimer(id, deadline) {
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = updateTimer(deadline);

    clock.innerHTML = "<span>" + timer.hours + "</span><span>" + timer.minutes + "</span><span>" + timer.seconds + "</span>";

    var spans = clock.getElementsByTagName("span");
    animateClock(spans[2]);

    if (timer.seconds == 59){
        animateClock(spans[1]);
    }

    if (timer.minutes == 59 && timer.seconds == 59){
        animateClock(spans[0]);
    }

    if (timer.total < 1) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      clock.innerHTML = "<span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span>";
    }

  }, 1000);
}

function hideOnLoad(clock, units){
  var c = document.getElementById(clock);
  var u = document.getElementById(units);
  c.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  u.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function clickStart(counter){
     var start = document.getElementById("del-countdown");
      start.addEventListener("click", function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter%2==0){

          $('#screen').transition({ y: '-500px' });
          var c = document.getElementById("clock");
          var u = document.getElementById("units");
          c.style.visibility = 'visible';
          u.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }else{

            $('#screen').transition({ y: '0px' });
             var c = document.getElementById("clock");
            var u = document.getElementById("units");
            c.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            u.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }, false);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var deadline = new Date("Jan 1, 2018 10:10:00");
  var counter = 1;

  hideOnLoad("clock", "units");
  clickStart(counter);
  startTimer("clock", deadline);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add border radius on `#screen` https://codepen.io/caseydev/pen/eWPWWw

Comment: Yes I know for this... But I need when you clicked on image, image go up. And you see half of image, other half is hidden... You only need to see part of image in circle